# what are the best practices to run Hive queries

Tags: hive, datastax-enterprise

Usually Hive queries takes some time to execute which could be few minutes to hours. If several hundred Java clients are executing Hive queries then potentially such clients will be waiting for long time to get the results and may time out due to network issues. Is there a asynchronous feature with Hive that can be used instead of synchronous behavior?

What are the best practices to mitigate such issues?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop job scheduler provides guaranteed capacity to production jobs and good response time to interactive jobs while allocating resources fairly between users. You can check the following blog.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/job-scheduling-in-hadoop/

There is no asynchronous feature with Hive